# XMLHttpRequest Bom exemplo aplicado

Tags: javascript

Olá, tudo certo? Vou explicar minha dúvida

Tenho uma array com vários nomes para automatizar uma lista de clientes e preciso enviar um por um em uma requisição get

Exemplo
site.com.br/api/cadastro/user/ >nome

Preciso percorrer toda a array, retirar um nome da mesma e fazer um get na api, esperar a resposta e passar para o próximo, e ao mesmo tempo mostrar um tipo de porcentagem de quanto ainda falta para terminar a array.

Obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisas de dividir isso em passos para teres o controlo de progresso.

Um exemplo seria assim, usando promises:

```js
function ajax(nome) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var url = 'https://httpbin.org/get?text=' + nome;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        resolve(json);
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  });
}

function processarPedidos(nomes, fn, cb) {
  var progress = document.querySelector('progress');
  progress.value = 0;

  (function processador(arr) {
    var proximo = arr.shift();
    if (!proximo) cb();
    else ajax(proximo).then(fn).then(function() {
    
      // atualizar a progress bar
      progress.value = 100 - (arr.length * 100 / nomes.length);
      // chamar o próximo
      processador(arr, fn, cb);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  })(nomes.slice());
}

var nomes = ['João', 'Ana', 'Maria', 'Rita', 'António', 'Paula'];

processarPedidos(nomes, function(json) {
  console.log(json.args);
}, function() {
  console.log('100%!!');
})
```

```html
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment: Chegando em casa já vou responder

Comment: Deu certo, o problema é que ele para quando o servidor não reconhece o cliente, andei pesquisando e achei o "Promise.reject", eu preciso usar ele para continuar a fila ? se sim como posso aplicar nessa function ? [edit: usei resolve("error"); e a fila continuou, é uma boa forma de resolver ?]

Comment: @PlanetWar ok, e se ele der erro deve contar na mesma para o `progress`? Nesse caso coloca o conteúdo de `then(` aqui também `.catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });`